# ¿A qué se debe que la conexión de telnet exceda el límite de tiempo en un servidor remoto?

Tags: linux, server, smtp

Tengo una aplicación en un servidor remoto que necesita enviar correos electrónicos pero hay un problema este no envia correos porque no logra conectarse al protocolo smtp.
he probado el siguiente comando

```
telnet smtp.mi.com.co 587
```

Y la respuesta arrojada desde mi servidor remoto es la siguiente:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Pensando que puede ser que haya problemas en mi proveedor de correos dicidí probar con otro en mi servidor, utilicé el de gmail (`smtp.gmail.com 587`) y me arrojó el mismo resultado.
Yo actualemente utilizo linux Ubuntu así que decidí probar los mismos comandos en mi local y los resultados fueron exitosos, no tuve problema al conectar tanto en `smtp.mi.com.co` como en `smtp.gmail.com` mi duda es ¿Habrá alguna configuración que acepte las conexiones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No resalté que mi servidor remoto estaba alojado en [Linode](https://www.linode.com/). Investigando un poco logré encontrar no se trataba algo técnico que pudiese solucionar en linux como tal o alguna configuración en especifico, simplemente se trataba de que [Linode](https://www.linode.com/) a partir de 2019 agrego una nueva [política para combatir el spam](https://www.linode.com/es/blog/linode/a-new-policy-to-help-fight-spam/)  y desde dicho año las cuentas creadas despues de 2019 tendrán bloqueado los puertos 25, 465, 587 de manera predeterminada para los envios de correos, la solución es mandar un ticket a linode para que estos sean habilitados.